# Virtual Box with smartcard reader device

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, smartcard

I'm using HID Omnikey 3121 smartcard reader and I'm trying to use in virtual box windows 7 vm. 
On ubuntu`(16.04)` side I installed pcsc drivers and I see using `pscs_scan` command that device is connected and smart card is inserted. 
The problem is that I can not see this device in vm.

In virtual box I have "Enable USB controller" checked but devices but i see "no devices available" when trying to add smart card reader.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you install the VirtualBox Extension Pack? https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.6-120293.vbox-extpack

Comment: ps. If the device is mounted and visible like a disk (just like an usb drive) that you need to unmount it first. The device can only be used by one OS at a time.

Comment: Yes i have installed VirtualBox Extension Pack, nothing changes only that i could pick usb 2.0 or 3

Comment: And no, device is not visible like a disk, also using df  it's not showed there

Comment: you might also need to add yourself to the vboxusers group: 
`sudo groupadd vboxusers` and then 
`sudo usermod -aG vboxusers userName`
After executing previous commands, logout from the host and then login again (reboot also works)

Comment: Forgot to mention to replace userName with your actual user name.

Comment: Wow, great, that actually helped. Thanks. Can you add it as answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a solution:
Make sure the VirtualBox Extension Pack is installed and also make sure to be a member of the vboxusers group (see commands below).

1. Make sure the group exists: `sudo groupadd vboxusers`
2. Add yourself to this group: `sudo usermod -aG vboxusers ${USER}`
3. Logout and login again (or reboot)

Good luck!